# What is the easiest way to create a toy image dataset on GCP Vertex AI?

Tags: python, image, gcloud, open-source, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Toy datasets are useful to share reproducible issues. I would like to easily create image datasets on Vertex AI from open-source data.

For example, [Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets) provides some public data sets ([boston_housing](https://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston), [cifar10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html), cifar100, fashion_mnist, [imdb](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eamaas/data/sentiment/), [mnist](https://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), reuters).

How to load one of them easily in a Vertex AI image dataset ? With *gcloud* commands and/or *Python* script for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have GCP credentials to perform the following actions, a Vertex AI dataset with single-label image can be created with the following commands.

1. Connect to your GCP project and activate a cloud shell console (at the top right)[image]
2. Install the [cifar2png](https://github.com/knjcode/cifar2png) Python package and import images as .png in a directory called *cifar10_png* on your local disk storage.

```
    $ pip install cifar2png
    $ cifar10 cifar10_png
```

3. Move the files to GC Storage. This operation can take few minutes depending the amount of data. Here we only move *test* images.

```
    $ BUCKET_NAME="your_bucket_name"
    $ gsutil -m -q cp -r cifar10_png/test gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/cifar10_png/test
```

4. Create an empty Vertex AI image dataset. Your project identifier is displayed by clicking on the top left [image]

```
    $ LOCATION="continent-zonenumber"
    $ PROJECT_ID="your_project_id"
    $ curl -X POST "https://${LOCATION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION}/datasets" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d '{"display_name": "<replace_by_your_table_name>", "metadata_schema_uri": "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/metadata/image_1.0.0.yaml"}'
```

5. Keep the identifier of the created dataset returned.[image]
6. Import the image in your dataset

```
    $ DATASET_ID="you_dataset_id"
    $ curl -X POST "https://${LOCATION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION}/datasets/${DATASET_ID}:import" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d  '{"import_configs": [{"gcs_source": {"uris": "gs://<replace_by_your_bucket_name>/cifar10_png/test"}, "import_schema_uri" : "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/image_classification_single_label_io_format_1.0.0.yaml"}]}'
```

7. Go to Vertex AI > Datasets and wait 5-10 minutes for the import to finish. More information about the creation of dataset for image classification [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/create-dataset).